# Meaning of "さっきまで都会風ぶっこいてたんだよ"

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, slang

Here's the context:

> A: 始めまして
>
> B: 始めまして
>
> C: 東京から[引]{ひ}っ[越]{こ}して来た子だよ
>
> B: 東京　どれくらい東京にいたの
>
> A: [幼稚園]【ようちえん】から４月までいました
>
> B: じゃ　私なんかよりも都会っ子だね
>
> C: よりって　ひか姉[根]【ね】っこからの[田舎]【いなか】っ子じゃん
>
> D: **さっきまで都会風ぶっこいてたんだよ**
>
> B: いや　ちょっと　気取ってみたという

I searched in jisho.org for **ぶっこ** or **ぶっこく** (cause of the いて conjugation for く-ending verbs) but they don't match, I hope the context is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ぶっこく is a slangy, colloquial and vulgar verb used in place of 言う, する, でいる etc. It has a contemptuous or mocking nuance, although it's not as offensive as ほざく/ぬかす. Look up ぶっ and こく separately for the etymology. 都会風ぶっこく in this context roughly means "to behave/speak like a city girl", but it sounds more slangy than this.

For some reason, ぶっこく is often used with 余裕. 余裕(を)ぶっこく means the same thing as [余裕をかます](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%99%E8%A3%95%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99), and it may be memorized as a slangy set expression.

Answer (score 2):

Looking up **ぶっこく** takes you nowhere because this word is made of **ぶっ** and **こく**.

> For ぶっ, https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/193337/meaning/m0u/
>
> For こく, [https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/76624/meaning/m0u/こく/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/76624/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%81%8F/)